# GitHub: How to add Gist to repository?

Tags: git, github, github-for-mac

I'm new to GitHub and have some questions. I'm using the [PullToRefreshView](https://github.com/chpwn/PullToRefreshView) project from GitHub. I've created [my own Fork](https://github.com/DennisMadsen/PullToRefreshView). Using the [GitHub for Mac](http://mac.github.com/), I've synchronized my own fork down to my computer.

On GitHub Gist I found a commit with some changes to one of the files from the original repository: https://gist.github.com/1611706. How can I add this to my own fork?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Easy way:**

- Merge this [Pull Request](https://github.com/DennisMadsen/PullToRefreshView/pull/1) using the [GitHub Merge button](https://github.com/blog/843-the-merge-button)
- Pull (synchronize) the changes from your GitHub repository.

**Less easy way:**

- Display in your browser [the raw version of the gist](https://raw.github.com/gist/1611706/f527d12e8cf0fc09af39d484de09ac9a009857d8/PullToRefreshView.m)
- Copy the content
- Open locally the `PullToRefreshView.m` file
- Replace its content with the content of the clipboard
- Stage the new version of the file
- Commit locally and push (publish) toward your GitHub repo

**Note:** There are [other approaches](https://www.google.com/search?q=merge+two+git+repositories), but considering the small history of the Gist, they're far too much complex.

**Note 2:** Please take into account that this change will only exist in your repo, not in the **master** (chpwn's) repo. You won't be able to transparently benefit from every upstream update, you'll have to merge them.

Comment: Ok, so there is no way connect the Gist directly to my repo, without copying their code. Thank you. I'll then use the less easy way. Can I remove your pull from my repo?

Comment: *Ok, so there is no way connect the Gist directly to my repo* -> There are some (see the first note) but they're a bit overkill.
*Can I remove your pull from my repo?* -> Just close it :)

Answer (score 1):

Further recent developments--[you can directly import from the github UI.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37144960/188963)