# Change lots of commit messages

Tags: git, github, gist

I transferred my [gist](https://gist.github.com/josephernest/3f22c5ed5dabf1815f16efa8fa53d476) and all its revisions into a [git repo](https://github.com/josephernest/wavfile.py) thanks to this great [Github import feature](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37144960/1422096).

But now all the commit messages are [empty](https://github.com/josephernest/wavfile.py/commits/master/wavfile.py):

> No commit message
>   UserA committed on GitHub 27 days ago

**How to change the commit message of all these 9 or 10 commits, one month later?**

(Is it possible directly in Github's website?)

Comment: You will have to rewrite the history of those commits in your branch.  Is anyone else sharing this branch?

Answer (score 1):

Well you can use `git rebase -i HEAD^8` to interactivly change the messages.
This will open an editor and you can change the commit messages and you change the word `pick` to `reword` and can now reword every single commit message.
Be aware that this action rewrites your whole history which means you have to do `git push --force` to update the remote repository.

By doing `git push --force` you will update the remote history as well, which means that contributer have to re-pull or even re-clone the repository to integrate the new history which can lead to horrible merges or even loss of changes.

Comment: Complementary note: if you don't understand what `git push --force` does, you should at least know that this is a potentially dangerous operation, don't run it blindly.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I will update the answer and add your information respectivly.

Comment: How to do this for all commits? should I do  `git rebase -i <numberofcommit>` ?

Comment: Something else: in the editor (is it a vim?) what should I write to rename to "First commit"? I tried `rFirst commit` (r for reword) then `ESC` then `:wq`, but then I get `Unknown command: rFirst commit`.

Comment: You can also start a new branch at the current tip to hold your old version, and do the interactive rebase to update the messages, and then do a rename to swap over the branches, though that maybe more phaff than it's worth.

Comment: @Basj you change the words 'pick' to 'reword' in the editor. You save the file, and then git starts to open every commit and let you change the commit message.

Comment: @ckruczek: with `nano` now as my default editor, this is what I get when doing `git rebase -i` : http://gget.it/8huetr9x/1.jpg. I tried to replace `noop` by `r` then save and quit, error (`fatal: Needed a single revision
Invalid commit name:`). Idem by replacing `noop` by `reword` and save and quit. What is wrong?

Comment: Ok I might missed something in my answer. You have to define how many commits you want to update. See the updated answer

Comment: The answer is right, you have to use `squash` which is the `git rebase -i HEAD~<number of commits to rebase>` but keep in mind that even if you choose 10 commits back you can have more commits since merge commits will be shown as well with all their commits. if you had 5 comits in merge you will see them as well.

Comment: @ckruczek I get `fatal: Needed a single revision invalid upstream HEAD~9`. The same with `HEAD^9`. Any idea?

Comment: Yes 9 was one to much I guess. So try 8 instead. I'll update my answer accordingly

Comment: @ckruczek  I tried with a new fresh and clean clone (can you try the same?) : `git clone https://github.com/josephernest/wavfile.py.git` `cd wavfile.py` `git rebase -i HEAD^8`. Then `fatal: Needed a single revision // invalid upstream HEAD^8`. Thanks in advance!